# Question about maximal ideals in a Polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I'm reading Freiligh and he has an example in a book, here it is:

Let $F = R$ and let $f(x) = x^2 + 1$. Which is well known to have no zeros in $R$ and thus is irreducible over $R$ by a theorem previously stated.

Then $<x^2+1>$ is a maximal ideal in $R[x]$. So $R[x]/<x^2 + 1>$ is a field.

This quotient ring is somehow isomorphic with the Complex numbers. I guess I'm having a hard time understanding why that is the case.

Being as simple as possible, can someone explain to me why that is the case. I don't know really advanced math.

Comment: For a proof see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786833/is-mathbb-rx-langle-x21-rangle-mathbb-rx-langle-x22-rangle), and [here](http://math.byu.edu/~forcader/zproof.pdf).

Comment: It's not so much a proof I would like to see as it's an understanding about what's happening in a more intuitive level. IF thats possible. I hear that proofs in abstract algebra are not really intuitive based. I guess I'm wondering why this quotient ring is bigger than the Real numbers, shouldnt it be smaller?

Comment: It is not smaller, because already $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)\simeq \mathbb{R}$. Such insights (to understand what a quotient really is) will help you more than fuzzy ideas on the intuitive level.

Comment: Okay, how can I understand what a quotient really is. From my text book, this construction should be the quotient ring, which is a set defined with the operations of Coset multiplication and coset addition. An example would be the Integers. Let's take $Z \3Z$ This defines the cosets of all multiples of 3. So one set will have {...0,3,6...} another {...1,4,7..} and the last {...2,5,8...}. This is the general Idea right?

Comment: Does this construction work differently when we are talking about polynomials?

Comment: No, this is exactly the same. For more examples, try [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23704/discussion-between-user121615-and-dietrich-burde).

Comment: Allright, I think I can get an understanding if I could get an understanding of exactly what this ideal looks like: $<x^2+1>$ This is $x^2+1$ multiplied by itself indefinitely?

Comment: I found this on the wikipedia you sent me: " Now consider the ring R[X] of polynomials in the variable X with real coefficients, and the ideal I = (X2 + 1) consisting of all multiples of the polynomial X2 + 1. The quotient ring R[X]/(X2 + 1) is naturally isomorphic to the field of complex numbers C, with the class [X] playing the role of the imaginary unit i. The reason: we "forced" X2 + 1 = 0, i.e. X2 = −1, which is the defining property of i. "  But it's the ideal the set of all multiples of $x^2+1$ not $x^2 + 1$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

$\mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(x) \rightarrow f(i)$.

Comment: But why is the ring constructed by $R[x]\<x^2 + 1>$ isomorphic to the complex numbers? Shouldn't the ring be smaller? I don't get it